# Should I commit to a job I cannot afford to keep?

Tags: interviewing, salary, contracting

An agency is submitting me to a job that has plenty of upsides, except for the pay. The jobs I typically get, and the ones I've been applying to lately, pay about twice what this one does. I will have serious financial problems if I accept this job and stay there a long time.

The job is nominally temp-to-perm. Normally, I'd be willing to take the job, do my best work, and discreetly look for a more substantial job on my off-hours. If I got another job, I'd give the appropriate notice and try to make my leaving as painless to them as possible.

However, the agency that submitted me feels that "temp-to-perm" means it *really* will go permanent. (I guess that's happened in the past.) They want to tell the client that I'd be committed to their job.

So even if I think I could ace the interview, and allay all their fears about being "overqualified", I'm not sure if I should even take interview if I intend to keep looking for a better paying job. And if I do, it would be with the understanding that I won't be looking for other work.

(There's a chance I could address my money issues by getting a second job night and/or weekends, but the agency doesn't even want the client to know that. It would make me sound less than committed.)

Should I commit to a job I cannot afford to keep?

EDIT: I didn't get the interview or the job. They decided I was likely to leave the job for more money or because I was bored. In other words, they doubted my commitment.

Comment: so ... you want to know... what to do? or do you want to know what to consider when making up your mind? or you want to discuss at the interview how you will keep looking for another job, or... what?

Comment: Voted to close because I did not see a question

Comment: Why would you even consider this employment, especially through the agency? I think employer does pay fair rate, your share is whats left after agency got their "piece"

Comment: @Strader Because I need the money

Comment: This will heavily depend on how much you need the money, how easily you can find another job and your moral values.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Three months. It doesn't seem like long, but the company folded owing me about a paycheck and a half. I've been borrowing money and I'm still likely to run out soon. In my industry, companies won't do very much hiring between now and mid-January.

Comment: @Dukeling (a) A lot. (b) It's been hard (c) a lot.

Comment: just get a temporary job doing something else why you search for something decent.... can't even see why you would contemplate this

Comment: @Kilisi  Just get a temporary job? "JUST GET A TEMPORARY JOB"? I've been looking for *any* jobs for three months -- and most of the ones I see *are* temporary! This would be the first job I've actually been offered!

Comment: Perhaps setting your sights too high, when I need money I take any menial job from labouring to cleaning.

Comment: Temporary job.  You can tend bar.  Drive for Uber or Lyft.  Work fast food  Wort part-time retail.  Paint houses (I've done this when an employer went belly and left me with no income).  Really, there are lots of things you can do to earn some money.  If your financial situation is as bad as you say it is then you will probably need to the extra income when you find somethin in your field.

Comment: @JimmyB, Okay, that's fair -- you're all talking about "survival" jobs. (Deep breath.) In my experience, they haven't been easy to get. The survival job I have now is irregular. Fast food places have never responded to my applications, and they don't really want temps. TaskRabbit doesn't show any jobs anymore. Uber rejected my car. (On the other hand, I have a good shot at a seasonal job that starts a month from now, paying even less than the one that prompted my original question.)

Answer (score 6):

> They want to tell the client that I'd be committed to their job.

I would never let any agency lie on my behalf.

Most likely, I'd pass on an interview with a company offering only 50% of what I thought I needed for a salary. That just seems to far off to reach a compromise in a negotiation.

If I thought there was any chance to get the company to agree to a salary in line with what I could accept I would go on the interview and give it my best shot. Then, assuming I wowed them, I'd negotiate hard for my desired salary.

But I'd never lie and use the word "committed" if I wasn't. And I'd never let anyone lie that I was committed when I wasn't.

And if the agency insisted on their approach, then they wouldn't be working with me any longer.

Comment: +1000000.
Why would you commit yourself to poverty while working full time?

Comment: @Strader I'm afraid the other option is another three months of unemployment. In other words, even worse poverty

Comment: Understand, in this case you do have to take it. But in this case i dont think you should commit to staying at the job that you cant afford. Sorry